# how i use backgroundService in iPhone with time interval?

Tags: titanium, titanium-modules

i Think this is very poor question. But, I don't understand 
1. how i use this. 
2. which type this working in device?
please any one help me?
Thanks in advance..!

Comment: what did u mean by 2. which type this working in device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer below links of background services for iOS and Android

1) [For iOS Services](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/119966/stopstart-ios-background-service)

2) [For Android Services](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Simple+Android+Services+in+Titanium)